# Are there abilities or effects that change the timing restriction of 'level up' abilities in M:tG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there effects that change the timing restrictions of level up cards (e.g. [Wizard Class](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wizard%20Class))? As far as I can tell, the various effects that affect casting of sorcery spells do not affect level up abilities despite the reminder text stating *"Gain the next level as a sorcery to add its ability."*

Comment: There are lots of things which stop activated abilities of a permanent being activated - are they of interest here, or do you care only about things which let you activate the ability of the Class card at instant speed?

Comment: As an aside, the activated abilities of Class cards are not level up abilities, despite their wording. CR 702.87c: "Some enchantments have the subtype Class and associated abilities that give them a class level. These are not the same as level up abilities and class levels do not interact with level counters."

Comment: 1) I'm mostly interested in if/how "sorcery speed" abilities might be activated at instant speed. @Ben P.'s answer is precisely what I was looking for. 
2) thanks for the clarification - the lack of counters is a relevant point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such abilities or effects.

The relevant rules are:

> 717.2a “[Cost]: Level N — [Abilities]” means “[Cost]: This Class’s level becomes N. Activate this ability only if this Class is level N-1 and **only as a sorcery**” and “As long as this Class is level N or greater, it has [abilities].”

and

> 307.5. If a spell, ability, or effect states that a player can do something only “any time they could cast a sorcery” or **“only as a sorcery,”** it means only that **the player must have priority, it must be during the main phase of their turn, and the stack must be empty**. The player doesn’t need to have a sorcery card they could cast. Effects that would preclude that player from casting a sorcery spell don’t affect the player’s capability to perform that action (unless the action is actually casting a sorcery spell).

There are no existing cards that modify these fundamental rules.

Comment: While I _believe_ this is correct, how did you determine there are no cards which modify these rules? There are for instance cards which modify the very similar rule 606.3 "A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent they control any time they have priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of their turn, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn."

Comment: Class cards haven't existed for very long, so looking through AFR, MID, and VOW for anything that modifies their rules was pretty easy. Of course, this answer could change any time new cards are released.

Comment: Oh, maybe you're asking how I verified that nothing modified 307.5 (and not how I verified that nothing modified 717.2a). In that case: I didn't. I've just played magic for a long time and have never noticed such a card. Further, I see 307.5 as a sort of "fundamental" rule that is unlikely to be affected by cards (though obviously anything is possible).